# Creating an Equation for $\arctan$ Given Three Points

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find the correct values of $a,b,c,d$ for the function $f(x) = a + b\arctan(cx + d)$ such that it crosses the following points: $(0.1,0.1),(1/3,1/3),(0.9,0.9)$ and I'm not sure how to go about it. Is there a way to do this? Would I need more than three points in order to find a unique solution?

Answer (score 0):

Each point gives you an equation in $a,b,c,d$, obtained by substituting the values of $x$ and $f(x)$ in the equation $f(x) = a + b \arctan(cx+d)$.
Since there are four parameters, you should generally expect to require four points.  Even then, the solution will generally not be unique.  In this case, note that changing the signs of $b$, $c$ and $d$ leaves the function unchanged: $-b \arctan(-cx -d) = b \arctan(cx+d)$ because $\arctan$ is an odd function.

For actually finding solutions of such systems of equations, I suspect you'll need to use numerical methods: e.g. Newton-Raphson, or whatever you find in your favourite CAS (e.g. fsolve in Maple).